# Warning shows when using SQLAlchemy with MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using flask and SQLAlchemy to build my app, but I got some problem can't be fixed. I setup my database in config.py

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/blog?charset=utf8mb4'
SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN = True
```

I have a db 'blog' in MySQL with utf8mb4 charset(at first it was utf8 ,also in config.py, others told me use utf8mb4 to solve it but didn't work).
Here is my models in models.py

```
from . import db


class Role(db.Model):
    role = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, primary_key = True, autoincrement = False)
    remark = db.Column(db.String(200))

    def __init__(self, role, remark):
        self.role, self.remark = role, remark

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    role = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, db.ForeignKey('role.role'),  nullable = False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique = True, nullable = False)
    pwd = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable = False)

    def __init__(self, name, pwd, role):
        self.name, self.pwd, self.role = name, pwd, role
```

When I run 'db.create_all()', I got a warning that shows all the time, even the two tables was created, it popup when I add rows to table.Here is the warning

```
Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xD6\\xD0\\xB9\\xFA\\xB1\\xEA...' for column 'VARIABLE_VALUE' at row 480")
```

Please help, I'm using MySQL57 and python35, windows.

Comment: I believe this is because whatever encoding that string is in, is not supported by MySQL. Don't really know much more about it than that without getting a bit more detail, but it appears to be an encoding issue.

Comment: But the warning also shows when I create the table

Comment: now I change MySQL to 55 edition,the warning is gone.I don't know why.